# Python and Pandas - Sorting data by datetime is not in ascending order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to sort some data using Python/Pandas by year and month for a line plot.

My code is:

```
df.groupby(df['EXTRACT_DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))['data'].sum().sort_values(ascending=True)
```

Which is returning:

[image]

Which is clearly not in order, but I'm not sure why and my data is like this:

[image: Sort]

Answer (score 3):

Change to `sort_index`, after `groupby` your `EXTRACT_DATE` became index , so when you do `sort_values` , it sort the data not the %Y-%m

```
df.groupby(df['EXTRACT_DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))['data'].sum().sort_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `.sort_values()` which sorts by the value (the sum in this case) and not by the index (the date). What you want to use instead is [`.sort_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html).

Comment: Yes of course, thank you! Wood for the trees with this one!